# Collect sinusoids of same frequency

Tags: python, sympy

I have an expression of many sinusoids.  Some frequencies are repeated, so I would like to collect the coefficients for identical frequencies.  Seems like either collect() or factor() should so the trick but they only work on simple expressions and fail when many variables are involved.  Is there a better way to collect terms?  Is there a way to help guide factor() to what variable to operate on like exists for collect()?   I am trying to manually simplify the equation into a particular form and I think cse() goes too far in reworking terms.  Examples below:

```
w, x, y, z = symbols('w x y z')
factor(z*sin(2*pi*x)+y*sin(2*pi*x), deep=True)
(y + z)⋅sin(2⋅π⋅x) #WORKS
factor(z*sin(2*pi*x*w)+y*sin(2*pi*x*w), deep=True)
(y + z)⋅sin(2⋅π⋅w⋅x) #WORKS
factor(z*sin(2*pi*x)+y*sin(2*pi*x)+z*sin(w)+2*y*sin(w), deep=True)
2⋅y⋅sin(w) + y⋅sin(2⋅π⋅x) + z⋅sin(w) + z⋅sin(2⋅π⋅x)  # FAILS – expected  Expected (2y + z)*sin(w) + (y+z)⋅sin(2⋅π⋅x)


collect(z*sin(2*pi*x)+y*sin(2*pi*x), x)
y⋅sin(2⋅π⋅x) + z⋅sin(2⋅π⋅x) # FAILS   expected (y+z)⋅sin(2⋅π⋅x)
collect(z*sin(2*pi*x)+y*sin(2*pi*x)+z*sin(w)+2*y*sin(w), x)
2⋅y⋅sin(w) + y⋅sin(2⋅π⋅x) + z⋅sin(w) + z⋅sin(2⋅π⋅x) #FAILS   Expected (2y + z)*sin(w) + (y+z)⋅sin(2⋅π⋅x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> w, x, y, z = symbols('w x y z')
>>> ex= z*sin(2*pi*x)+y*sin(2*pi*x)+z*sin(w)+2*y*sin(w)
>>> ex
2*y*sin(w) + y*sin(2*pi*x) + z*sin(w) + z*sin(2*pi*x)
>>> collect(ex, [sin(w), sin(2*pi*x)])
(y + z)*sin(2*pi*x) + (2*y + z)*sin(w)
```

Reference: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html?highlight=collect

Comment: This is basically what I need so Thank You for your response. For now, I can manually enumerate the sum and differences of frequencies to direct collect().  I was hoping there was an automated function that would automatically check for duplicate frequencies.

Additionally, I had to totally expand the equation for collect to pick up all the terms.  I had done some previous simplification to make the equation more readable but it seemed to confuse collect().

Comment: Full expansion before collecting, that is right... Check out sympy documentation, you should be able to automate the harmonic functions list extraction.